# How to view book summary on Kindle reader

Tags: kindle

When I open a book for the first time on my Kindle reader it no longer shows me the book summary (about this book).
How do I get it to show?

I have tried everything on reading options but I can't find the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for but maybe this will be sufficient. When you are in the library on your Kindle, to the right of the title there are three little dots. Click/touch that and then select the option that shows the book in the Amazon store. That gets you to the Amazon page with the description, reviews, etc. I just figured this out myself. I wish it was easier than that -- just gives us the "back cover" of the book.

Comment: I don't think the original poster is trying to see the book description in the Kindle store. They're trying to find the "About this book" screen once the book is actually opened. I'm actually trying to figure this out myself, hence how I came across this post, (thanks Google.) LOL! Doing this, and looking at the description on the actual book details page within the store itself are 2 completely different things. I can see where you would be very confused with this! Amazon makes this incredibly stupidly harder than it needs to be. PSSS, Amazon! Oh, yoo hoo! Are you listening?

Comment: @clgilland - I was probably grasping at straws myself. It is very irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Older Paperwhite Owners

To find the book descriptions now,

Go pass the customer reviews and you will see Product Description. This is where you will find the book description now. Why they moved them is a mystery to me. Before I download a book, I want a small description

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

on the Paperwhite- Within any book, click the Aa and then More and it’s listed there and will update for all books going forward. Hope this helps!